# Javascript code to Puppeteer for(...of...)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, selector

I have the following javascript code, which I want to implement in puppeteer, to do something like:

```
   await page.click(myDivs[0])
```

```js
 const myDivs = [];
     for (const div of page.querySelectorAll("div.b-swatch-value-wrapper")) {
        if (div.querySelector("span.b-swatch-value--orderable") !== null) {
          myDivs.push(div.b-swatch-value-wrapper);
            }
        }
```

I probably didnt explain it properly.
I want to get every div, which contains the class "b-swatch-value-wrapper" +
have a span child which contains the class "b-swatch-value--orderable".
(Because some contain it, and some doesnt).

Like this its obviously not working, but how do I do this? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `myDivs.push(div.b-swatch-value-wrapper);` -> `myDivs.push(div.querySelector("span.b-swatch-value--orderable"));`?

Comment: I explained it more properly above. I only want to add the divs with the class "b-swatch-value-wrapper" when they have a span child, which contains the class b-swatch-value--orderable".

Comment: `myDivs.push(div)` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page` is a puppeteer variable in the Node.js context, while `querySelectorAll` and `querySelectorAll` are methods of document and elements in the browser context. These contexts cannot be mixed. Some serializable data can be transferred between them via `page.evaluate()` and similar functions. You can get an array of element handlers in this way (but element handlers have their own API, see details in the [documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle)).

```js
const myDivs = [];
for (const div of await page.$$("div.b-swatch-value-wrapper")) {
  if (await div.$("span.b-swatch-value--orderable") !== null) {
    myDivs.push(div);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. One more question. Isnt it possible to do something like:  `await page.click(myDivs[1]);` with it now? I get the error:  Error: JSHandles can be evaluated only in the context they were created!

Comment: Try `await myDivs[1].click()`  — see [`elementHandle.click()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions).